# Steam on Ubuntu can't connect to steam servers

Tags: steam

```
(gnome-terminal:11366): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get: the format string may not contain '&' (key 'monospace-font-name' from schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface'). This call will probably stop working with a future version of glib.
Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 needs to be installed
Package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 needs to be installed
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1447125378)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1447125378)
[2015-11-21 19:45:19] Startup - updater built Nov  9 2015 18:23:22
[2015-11-21 19:45:19] Verifying installation...
[2015-11-21 19:45:19] Verification complete
[2015-11-21 19:45:23] Shutdown
sketto@Ubuntu-Dev:~$ sudo apt-get install libGL.so.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libGL.so.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libGL.so.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this

install the packages that steam says needs to be installed.

Install `libgl1-mesa-dri:i386` and `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` with this command

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

if that doesn't work you can do this. Run these commands.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Reinstall steam with this command.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall steam
```

Comment: let me know if this works.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer did help you, please don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: It eventually turned out to be a firewall issue on my router.

Comment: Helped me solve a similar issue (where I could guarantee no firewall). Thanks, @Neil !